# What's The Best Data Structure For Ignoring Or Removing Some Of Elements In DataSet In Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, iterator

I have a set of objects and i wanna check out each of elements with previous elements.
In each time `if(thisElement % previousElement == 0)` I want to ignoring `previousElement` to prevent checking again because of time complexity.
How can i decrease size of `DataSet` if condition is true?
Is it better to marking and moving `previousElement` to first of `DataSet` or removing it at all?
I used `ArrayList` of objects but i couldn't move or remove it.I also used `Iterator` but it should have one loop inside another and it's complicated.How can i implement this algorithm in optimal time?
i want to move or remove previousElement in O(1).
this is my code:

```
public static int count_max(ArrayList<Node> nodes){
        
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int counter = 0;
        System.err.println("nodes: "+nodes);
        for(Node n : nodes){
        
            int index = nodes.indexOf(n);
            for(int i = index - 1 ; i >= 0 && nodes.get(i).mark == 0 ; i--){
            
                counter++;
                if(n.number % nodes.get(i).number == 0){
                    
                    n.pred = i;
                    nodes.get(i).mark = 1;
                    n.count = nodes.get(i).count + 1;
                    if(n.count > max)
                        max = n.count;
                    //nodes.remove(i);

                    break;
                }
            
            }

        }
        return max;
    }
```

the problem is find maximum count of divisible numbers given for example  consider [3, 4, 6, 8 ,10, 18 ,21 ,24] are given. the answer is 3 because of [3 , 6 , 18 ] or [4 , 8 , 24] all of members should be divisible  what's your solution to find this in o(nlogn) or a bit bigger.i don't want in o(n^2)

Comment: Are you trying to write a method that performs some sort of check on two consecutive elements and removes the first of the pair from the data structure if the test fails?

Comment: I'm quite confused. Do you want to skip `thisElement % previousElement == 0` comparison? Or what is the goal you want to achieve here?

Comment: Could you show us some code that you want to optimize? You could show what you want done logically with an inefficient data structure and point to where your presumed problem is.

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

You can use a `Set<T>`. The `remove` method returns `true` if the specified element was present in the set. The `add` method returns `true` if the specified element was not yet present in the set

Comment: @OLEGSHA yes it's a sorted list and i want to find maximum of divisable set of numbers in minimum time

Comment: @Amongalen actually i want to find maximum count of divisable numbers.for this, i first sorted list and then i want to find maximum count of divisable numbers in minimum time.

Comment: @corsiKa i added my code

Answer (score 1):

It could have been better if you had provided the logic you impemented but, based on your explanation, what I understood is, you want to remove the **Previous Element** if it is completely dividing  **Current Element** from the List. If that so, below mentioned way is easy to follow

MainClass.class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(2);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(8);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(9);
    int i = 1;

    System.out.println("Size of List: " + list.size());
    while (i < list.size()) {
        System.out.println("i : " + i);
        System.out.println("Values : " + list.get(i) + ", " + list.get(i - 1));
        if (list.get(i) % list.get(i - 1) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Removing: " + list.get(i - 1));
            list.remove(i - 1);
            i = 1;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("After removing elements(if any), size is: " + list.size());
    for (int val : list) {
        System.out.print(val + " ");
    }
}
```

what this code doing is, it starts from **i=1** and it keeps on checking whether **(i-1)th** value divides **ith** value or not. If **(i-1)th** is dividing **ith** value then, **i** is set to "1" because we need to start from beginning and maintain the **condition** i.e.., **(i-1)th** value should not divide **ith** value. And you can guess that, if any value is not divisible by it's previous element then, we simply increment the **i** till it is less than the size of the List.

Note: I assumed that you want to maintain above mentioned **condition** throughout the List


I hope this might help you in some way to solve your issue. And this post can be edited if anyone feels needs to be.

Comment: thanks.i want to check with all of previous elements.when i try remove shows error as concurrent exception.how can i fix this?

Comment: @a.programmer, can you give an example List where you want to check with all previous elements.

Comment: @B Sangappa the problem is find maximum count of divisible numbers given for example  consider [3, 4, 6, 8 ,10, 18 ,21 ,24] are given. the answer is 3 because of [3 , 6 , 18 ] or [4 , 8 , 24] all of members should be divisible  what's your solution to find this in o(nlogn) or a bit bigger.i don't want in o(n^2)

Comment: @a.programmer, I can see 21 ad 24 are also divisible by 3, in that case, the answer would be 5 right? or am I missing something?